# Messaging App With Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a messaging app, here's my model,

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I wants to order the Users based upon who sent a message to `request.user` & to whom `request.user` sent a message most recently! As we see on social networks.

This is what I tried,

```
users = User.objects.filter(
    Q(sender__receiver=request.user) | Q(receiver__sender=request.user)
).annotate(Max('receiver')).order_by('-receiver__max')
```

This code is working fine only when `request.user` sends someone a message (It re-orders their name & place it to the top). But, It's not changing the order of users in case if someone sends a message to `request.user`.

I also tried,

```
users = Message.objects.filter(
    Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)
).order_by("created_at")
```

But, I could't filter out the distinct users. It's showing equal number of users as messages. Also, I have to use `{{ users.sender }}` OR `{{ users.receiver }}` in order to print the users name which is a problem itself in case of ordering & distinct users.

Please help me, how can I do that?

Comment: whats your user model fields.

Comment: @AnkushVerma Sir, it's build in model by django

Comment: @Randomix Please do not tag other users like this. It is annoying. People will answer if they have the time and know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

your django query

```
users = Message.objects.filter(
    Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)
).order_by("created_at")
```

is ok. you get list of all the messages sent by or received by the user. But what you want is to be done in the templates.

in your template to get all the messages in defined order. use this...

```
{% for msg in users %}
 {% if user is msg.sender %}
  sent to {{ msg.receiver }} : {{ the_message }}
 {% else %}
  sent by {{ msg.sender }} : {{ the_message }}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope you get what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sir, it will not filter out the distinct users!